# Input type number is not being set on $scope init. How could I set the input on the controller init?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that have defined a route parameters when I open the controller from a link with its parameters the init capture those params but it does not show the data on the form. The init function is ran on controller initialization and it captures all route parameters well but when I assign it to the model on the scope the input is not getting the value. I tried $digest and $apply but that does not work there. How can I make the number input show the value from the route only on initialization?

My route configuration :

```
 when('/mypage/:ofid/:nfid?', {
            templateUrl: 'admin/templates/mytemplate.html',
            controller: 'MyTemplateController'
          }).
```

My controller-fragment:

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .controller('MyTemplateController', ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', .....
    function ($scope, $log, $routeParams, ...) {
        $scope.oldId;
        $scope.newId;   
        ...
        $scope.init = function () {
            $scope.oldId = $routeParams.ofid;
            newId = $routeParams.nfid;

        }
        $scope.init();
    }
```

Template fragment:

```
            <input type="number"
                   class="form-control"
                   ng-model="oldId"
                   required/>
```

Comment: what is  the datatype of `oldId`?

Comment: number. I tried   $scope.oldId =  parseInt(routeParams.ofid) but it didi not work

Comment: $scope.oldId = parseInt(routeParams.ofid) ?

Comment: yes  parseInt I fixed the typo

Comment: if you hard code it, does it work? `ng-init="oldId=2"`

Comment: no it does not work vent if I put in the input ng-init="2"  it also does not work

Comment: is this a typo?  your route says `MyTemplateController` but your listed controller is `MyPageController`....

Comment: yes I fixed the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$routeParams` are passed as strings, and parsing is required for using these in numeric inputs.
Using `$scope.oldId = parseInt($routeParams.ofid);` works for this situation.

```
app.controller('MyTemplateController', ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $log, $routeParams) {
    $scope.oldId;
    $scope.newId;
    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.oldId = parseInt($routeParams.ofid);
      $scope.newId = $routeParams.nfid;
      $log.log($scope.oldId, $scope.newId);
    };
    $scope.init();
  }
]);
```

The `$log.log($scope.oldId, $scope.newId);` at the end of the `init` shows `2, '1'` in the Chrome console, which is definitely proof that the `parseInt` worked, and the textbox is filled correctly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Oc777cYulT11KQMqdnmd?p=preview

Comment: I tried the parse first and it does not work but I retried with your post and this works not sure why now but is the solution

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
ng-init="desiredValue = $scope.realValue"
```

According to angular's documentation

"The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope."

But should be used with caution

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: how do you translate this to the fragment I posted ? It is the desiredValue any variable ?? Alos if you check the comment ng-init="oldId=2" is not working. I tested this using the desired value as my model names and it does not work

Comment: desiredValue would be the value you want to be displayed. realValue is the value you will assign to the new variable. It can also be a fixed value, such as : ng-init ="$scope.yourVal = true"

Comment: This did not work for me getting the value from route parameters

Comment: store the value on the scope within your controller, then you pass the controller value in the init call